# 3-dimensional Boolean cube of Squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Do there exist positive integers $A, B, C$ such that all seven numbers $$A, B, C, A+B, B+C, A+C, A+B+C$$ are perfect squares?

Comment: This is the perfect cuboid problem. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick)

Comment: Thank you @DenisShatrov. Could you please post this as an answer do that we can close the question? (Alternatively, I may remove it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If such $(A, B, C)$ exist, then $(\sqrt{A}, \sqrt{B}, \sqrt{C})$ are sides of a perfect cuboid (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick)).  Such a cuboid has not yet been found.